# Evitar recarga de la pagina (usando form, input con javascript y html)

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, input

estoy aprendiendo Javascript (y tambien HTML) desde 0, y estoy buscando la manera mas simple y entendible, de lograr lo siguiente:

El usuario ingresa una temperatura mediante un input dentro de un form, esta se recupera con document.getElementById, y luego se "postea" un mensaje en la pagina mediante el método .innerText.
Creo que el problema en mi código es que luego de ingresar la temperatura se refresca la pagina, he intentado con preventDefault() pero no pude. Adjunto el código

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>¿Como esta el clima?</h1> 

        <form id="formulario" onsubmit="saludar()" >
            <input class="col-8" id="uniqueID" placeholder="Indique la temperatura(solo numeros enteros)"></div>
        </form>

        <div id="displaytxt">"Aqui se muestra el texto"</div>   
    </div>

    <script src="javascript.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function saludar(){
    var temp = document.getElementById("uniqueID").value

    if (temp >= 0 && temp <= 16){                    //0-16
        document.getElementById("displaytxt").innerText="está fresco para pasear en jaula";      
    }
    else if(temp > 16){              //>16
        document.getElementById("displaytxt").innerText="maldicion va a ser un dia hermoso";
    }
    else if(temp <0){         //podria poner solo un else aca?
        document.getElementById("displaytxt").innerText="el arte es morirse de frio";

    }
}
```

Comment: prueba con `onsubmit="event.preventDefault();saludar()"`

Comment: muchas gracias @masterguru , esto lo pondria dentro del tag HTML, cierto?

Comment: No, lo pones en el tag `<form>` sustituyendo el onsubmit que tienes ahora por eso y ya esta. No es lo más optimo, pero funciona

Comment: buenisimo, lo acabo de probar y funciono! muchas gracias